# I want to continue looping even when no-data-found and use index by..getting 'no data found error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using sqldeveloper. I have to use INDEX BY for this program.

Department table has `ID's 10,20,50,60,80,100`.

Currently the program prints dept_names for id's 10 and 20 and then quits.

```
DECLARE
TYPE dept_table_indexby is TABLE OF
  departments.department_name%TYPE
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
dept_table_arr dept_table_indexby;
v_department_id  departments.department_id%TYPE := 10;
BEGIN 
  for i in 1..10 loop
  BEGIN
    select department_name into dept_table_arr(i)
    from departments
    where department_id = v_department_id;
    v_department_id := v_department_id + 10;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    --null; /* tried this option, still control exits the loop */
    dbms_output.put_line('in loop : ' || dept_table_arr(i));
  end;
  end loop;

  for i in dept_table_arr.first..dept_table_arr.last loop
  dbms_output.put_line('department name: outside loop ' || dept_table_arr(i));
  end loop;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure where the error is.

My guess is because you are trying to asign NULL to dept_table_arr(i) when ID=30

Im not familiar with oracle sintaxis, but here are my suggestion:

1 - Easier but couldnt test it by myself.

```
SELECT COALESCE(department_name , '') into dept_table_arr(i)
FROM departments
WHERE department_id = v_department_id;
```

> The COALESCE function takes two or more compatible arguments and returns the first argument that is not null.

---

2 - Longer but know will work

```
SELECT COUNT(department_name) into int_department
FROM departments
WHERE department_id = v_department_id;

IF int_department > 0 THEN
    SELECT department_name into dept_table_arr(i)
    FROM departments
    WHERE department_id = v_department_id;
ELSE 
   dept_table_arr(i) := "";
END IF;

v_department_id := v_department_id + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

1)

```
 select department_name into dept_table_arr(i)
    from departments
    where department_id = v_department_id;
    v_department_id := v_department_id + 10;
```

When *no_data_found* occured v_department will not update value, after two iteration it will always remain 30.

2)

```
 for i in dept_table_arr.first..dept_table_arr.last loop
  dbms_output.put_line('department name: outside loop ' || dept_table_arr(i));
  end loop;
```

In this loop *i* variable changes from 1 to 10 (10 times) but your array have only six values.

After fixing errors:

```
DECLARE
TYPE dept_table_indexby is TABLE OF
  departments.department_name%TYPE
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
dept_table_arr dept_table_indexby;
v_department_id  departments.department_id%TYPE := 0; --start with 0
k number;
BEGIN 
  for i in 1..10 loop
  BEGIN
    v_department_id := v_department_id + 10; --update v_department_id before select
    select department_name into dept_table_arr(i)
    from departments
    where department_id = v_department_id ; 

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    null; /* tried this option, still control exits the loop */
  end;
  end loop;
  --Associative arrays must be processed with .first and .next
  k:= dept_table_arr.first;
  while (k is not null)
    loop
--      dbms_output.put_line(k);
      dbms_output.put_line('department name: outside loop ' || dept_table_arr(k) );
      k:= dept_table_arr.next(k);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Didn't know that associative arrays need to be accessed in a particular way with .first and .next instead of .first and .last

Answer (score 0):

Use goto statement. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_goto_statement.htm

```
BEGIN 
  for i in 1..10 loop
  BEGIN
    <<loopstart>> /* Where to start looping again when reach exception*/
    v_department_id := v_department_id + 10; --update in beginning like ksa said
    select department_name into dept_table_arr(i)
    from departments
    where department_id = v_department_id;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    goto loopstart; /* Use this instead */
    dbms_output.put_line('in loop : ' || dept_table_arr(i));
  end;
```